Finding Approximation Properties and Integrability Conditions in $L^1(\mu)$
Struggling to connect the hints for this question. A trivial answer for the set A seems to me to just be the null set. But clearly that's not enough.
Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a measure space. Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given and $u \in L^1(\mu)$.
(a) Prove that there exists a set $A \in \mathcal{A}$ and $M \geq 1$ such that $\mu(A) < \varepsilon$ and $\lvert u(x) \rvert \leq \sqrt{M}$ for all $x \in A^c$.
(Hint: Use the Markov inequality.)
(b) Prove that there exists a function $g \in L^\infty(\mu)$ such that
$$
\int \lvert g - u \rvert \, d\mu < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}.
$$
(Hint: Note that $L^\infty(\mu)$ is dense in $L^1(\mu)$ (why?). Use this to find the required function $g$.)
(c) Prove that there exists $\delta > 0$ such that
$$
\int_B \lvert u \rvert \, d\mu < \varepsilon
$$
for any $B \in \mathcal{A}$ with $\mu(B) < \delta$.
(Hint: Use part (b) and note that $\lvert u \rvert \leq \lvert u - g \rvert + \lvert g \rvert$.)
Would greatly appreciate a detailed explanation or step-by-step proof for each part. Any hints or insights into the intuition behind the steps would also be helpful. Currently struggling to link the given hints.

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.
